# How to display html table in android screen(not in web view)

Tags: android, jsoup

trying to display this html table [image]

in android app .this image is just a scap.it contains lot of data .here is html structure
[image]
based on this structure i want to display above table in android app
i tried by placing all dt tags static and displaying dd tags with following code

```
String[] ddsTexts = new String[dds.size()];
            List l = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < dds.size(); i++) {
                ddsTexts[i] = dds.get(i).ownText();
                System.out.println(ddsTexts);
                l.add(ddsTexts[i]);
            }
```

.but it is not working if table format is changing .irrespective of table content ,i want to display it on android screen based on structure.how can i do it.thanks

Answer (score 1):

**The direct answer to your question:** You cannot use HTML tables outside of WebViews. In general, HTML doesn't belong in an Android app outside of WebViews and some limited formatting (e.g. `<strong>` or `<em>` tags) in TextViews.

**The problem with your provided code:** You are using System.out.println to try to output the HTML. This simply logs the line to the logcat (and not in a standard way either). Android relies on [layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and [Views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) to present the user interface.

If you don't want to use a WebView, the most appropriate method of displaying a table would be to parse the data and display it in a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html).

Comment: Okay i am using table layout Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
i.putExtra("ddss", ddsTexts);
in table second column displaying that ddtexts one by one